# Qt C++ moveToThread()

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I've just started working with Qt on Windows and read about moveToThread() function. Would it be ok if I write like this:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QThread* thread;
public:
    void GoToThread() {
        thread = new QThread();
        this->moveToThread(thread);
    }
    void DoWork() {
        //long work
    }
};

Worker* w = new Worker();
w->GoToThread();
w->DoWork();
```

And what exactly would this code do? Would it put itself to the thread? Would I be able to call DoWork() outside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you gave, `DoWork()` would execute on the caller's thread.

If you want `DoWork()` to be done on the `Worker` object's thread, you should have `DoWork()` be a slot that can be invoked either by emitting a signal that it has been connected to or by calling `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` to 'call' it.

Basically, moving a `Q_OBJECT` to another thread makes that `Q_OBJECT` use an event queue associated with that thread, so any events delivered to that object via the event queue will be handled on that thread.

Answer (score 3):

That will move the QObject to the new thread and on top of what *Michael Burr* already said you should take a look in the documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#details) because you miss at least a connect thread finished to deleteLater for your QObject (and this will cause a memory leak)